# Change default application

Tags: file-association, calibre

How can I change the default application within Calibre when opening a PDF? Now it opens Adobe Reader, but I would like to open another application.
Can somebody let me know how to do that, because I can not find the setting?

Thanks in advance
Marco

Comment: https://jb-blog.readthedocs.io/en/latest/posts/0016-how-to-change-what-program-calibre-uses-to-open-stuff.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows, hit alt+V or right click the item and select "view", then in the bottom left corner there is an option "Open With" - choose your default pdf viewer.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Pleassss Phil, read my post before you give an answer, because I say within Calibre.

Comment: @Marco, association of an application with a document type is an OS setting, not Calibre. For Linux, edit .desktop settings.

Comment: @marco, the instructions i gave you are **for changing default application 
 for pdf** within calibre. open the application, find you pdf inside of the calibre viewer and proceed as I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

This procedure might help :

- Use the View icon in calibre to execute "View specific format"
- Click on PDF
- Use the button "Open PDF with ..."
- The dialog of "Choose a program to open PDF files" opens up.
  You will see listed some options that you may choose, or use the
  button "Browse computer for program".

[image]